# Field recording databases

Tags: field-recording, database, free, archive, wiki

Freesound.org seems to be the largest and most reliable source of unprocessed field recordings (with a good share of pitch-shifted monster sounds too). I struggle to find alternatives of comparable size and quality.

What other databases exist? (I am especially interested in free/open databases with CC licenses, that may be used for R&D, rather than commercial ends)

Comment: You seemed to have answered your own question very well.

Comment: I've been appending my findings since originally posting the question. I'm hoping others will chime in or comment on what I found so far. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

here's another one:

[freeSFX](http://www.freesfx.co.uk/)

+ Easy to navigate thematic organization

+ Curated generally useful incidental sounds

+ Free commercial use, provided not main focus ([full license](http://www.freesfx.co.uk/info/eula/))

- relatively small collection (a couple of thousand sounds in my estimation)

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer, feel free to [add your finds](https://sound.stackexchange.com/posts/39691/edit)...

## Field Recording Databases

> **Freesound** >> http://freesound.org/   (added by [yunque](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/16291/yunque))
>
> + Search by license, format, bitrate, sample rate, tags, etc.
>
> + Open project, user-based (can search similar sounds recorded by the same person).
>
> - Variable quality.

---

> **British Library Sounds Maps** >> http://sounds.bl.uk/sound-maps/ (added by [yunque](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/16291/yunque))
>
> + Huge!
>
> - Search by keyword or category only.
>
> - No info about bitrate, etc.
>
> - Mostly complex environments, not isolated noises.

---

> **findsounds** >> http://www.findsounds.com/ (added by [yunque](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/16291/yunque))
>
> + Search by format, bitrate, sample rate.
>
> - Links to other websites, license info not obvious.

---

> **SoundBible** >> http://soundbible.com/ (added by [yunque](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/16291/yunque))
>
> + License info.
>
> - Search by filename only.

---

> **Geluid van Nederland** >> http://www.geluidvannederland.nl/ (added by [yunque](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/16291/yunque))
>
> + CC 3.0 entirely
>
> - Search by tag only.

---

> **Macaulay Library** >> http://macaulaylibrary.org/ (added by [yunque](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/16291/yunque))
>
> + Huge!
>
> - $ :[

---

> **Nature Sounds . ca** >> http://nature-downloads.naturesounds.ca/ (added by [yunque](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/16291/yunque))
>
> + Outdoors
>
> - mp3 only

---

> **freeSFX** >> http://www.freesfx.co.uk/ (added by [joseem](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/18128/joseem))
>
> + Easy to navigate thematic organization
>
> + Curated generally useful incidental sounds
>
> + Free commercial use, provided not main focus ([full license](http://www.freesfx.co.uk/info/eula/))
>
> - relatively small collection (a couple of thousand sounds in my estimation)